# Racetrack plotter

Tags: python, python-2.x, numpy, community-challenge, matplotlib

My [Racetrack](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5623/52915) is just that. A Racetrack. You can't race it (yet) because I had trouble with collision detection, but I wanted to share it anyway.

It creates a base polygon by using `numpy` and [`shapely`](http://toblerity.org/shapely/project.html). `matplotlib` (together with [`descartes`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/descartes)) does the plotting and `cPickle` is used to write states to file so the exact same track can be plotted later.

This is my first Python script using `argparse` instead of `sys` for argument handling. I'm especially interested in whether the way I implemented it is up to par.

The way it's structured is probably not the best either and as always I'm not too fond of my naming. I stuck to `-r` and `-w` for reading and writing because it seemed intuitive, but deeper in the code `load_state` and `save_state` are used. I'm not sure this is acceptable and which of both I should stick with (if any of those at all).

Under the argument parsing I have a couple of `BOLD_SNAKE_CASE` variables which are pseudo constants. There's probably a better way to do this. Some of those can be freely changed by the user, others shouldn't. I think it's self explanatory enough, but feel free to comment.

As said, it was supposed to be part of an actual Racetrack-game. So extendability is important. I like extra features, but those are a pain in the behind to implement if the code isn't modular.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import shapely.geometry as sg
from argparse import ArgumentParser
from descartes.patch import PolygonPatch
from cPickle import load, dump

# Argument handling
parser = ArgumentParser(description='Racetrack')
parser.add_argument(
    'InnerAmplitude',
    type=float,
    help='For example 0.1'
    )
parser.add_argument(
    'OuterAmplitude',
    type=float,
    help='For example 0.2, should be higher than InnerAmplitude'
    )
parser.add_argument(
    "-v",
    "--verbose",
    action="store_true",
    help="increase output verbosity"
    )
mutex = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
mutex.add_argument(
    "-r",
    "--read",
    action="store_true",
    help="read state from file"
    )
mutex.add_argument(
    "-w",
    "--write",
    action="store_true",
    help="write state from file"
    )

args = parser.parse_args()

# Define size of inner and outer bounds, between those is the Racetrack
INNER_AMPLITUDE = args.InnerAmplitude
OUTER_AMPLITUDE = args.OuterAmplitude
DIAMETER = OUTER_AMPLITUDE - INNER_AMPLITUDE

SIZE = 1.5
OUTER_WIDTH = 2

MINIMUM_POINTS = 5
MAXIMUM_POINTS = 15

LOAD_FILE = "state_file"
SAVE_FILE = LOAD_FILE

def load_state():
    with open(LOAD_FILE, "r") as file:
        np.random.set_state(load(file))

def save_state():
    with open(SAVE_FILE, "w") as file:
        dump(np.random.get_state(), file)

# Possibility to fix seed
if args.verbose:
    print (np.random.get_state())
if args.read:
    load_state()
elif args.write:
    save_state()

# A function to produce a pseudo-random polygon
def random_polygon():
    nr_points = np.random.randint(MINIMUM_POINTS, MAXIMUM_POINTS)
    angle = np.sort(np.random.rand(nr_points) * 2 * np.pi)
    dist = 0.3 * np.random.rand(nr_points) + 0.5
    return np.vstack((np.cos(angle)*dist, np.sin(angle)*dist)).T

# Base polygon
poly = random_polygon()

# Create a shapely ring object from base polygon
inner_ring = sg.LinearRing(poly)
outer_ring_inside = inner_ring.parallel_offset(DIAMETER, 'right', join_style=2, mitre_limit=10.)
outer_ring_outside = inner_ring.parallel_offset(OUTER_WIDTH * DIAMETER, 'right', join_style=2, mitre_limit=10.)

# Revert the third ring. This is necessary to use it to produce a hole
outer_ring_outside.coords = list(outer_ring_outside.coords)[::-1]

# Inner and outer polygon
inner_poly = sg.Polygon(inner_ring)
outer_poly = sg.Polygon(outer_ring_inside, [outer_ring_outside])

# Create the figure
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)

# Convert inner and outer polygon to matplotlib patches and add them to the axes
ax.add_patch(PolygonPatch(inner_poly, facecolor=(0, 1, 0, 0.4),
    edgecolor=(0, 1, 0, 1), linewidth=3))
ax.add_patch(PolygonPatch(outer_poly, facecolor=(1, 0, 0, 0.4),
    edgecolor=(1, 0, 0, 1), linewidth=3))

# Finalization
ax.set_aspect(1)
plt.title("Racetrack")
plt.axis([-SIZE, SIZE, -SIZE, SIZE])
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Example usage:

```
python racetrack.py -w 0.1 0.25
```

Example output:

[image: example racetrack]

Not all tracks are playable, since there is nothing checking whether the angles are too sharp. This isn't considered a problem at the moment.

Comment: Is the racetrack the red area? Then what does the green area mean?

Comment: @mkrieger1 The white area is the racetrack. The green and red are borders.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> This is my first Python script using `argparse` instead of `sys` for argument handling. I'm especially interested in whether the way I implemented it is up to par.

You nailed it :-)

> Under the argument parsing I have a couple of BOLD_SNAKE_CASE variables which are pseudo constants. There's probably a better way to do this.

That's the common practice in Python, and it's fine like that.
Except for these:

> ```
> INNER_AMPLITUDE = args.InnerAmplitude
> OUTER_AMPLITUDE = args.OuterAmplitude
> DIAMETER = OUTER_AMPLITUDE - INNER_AMPLITUDE
> ```

As these are values derived from the command line arguments.
The parsing logic would be better in a `main()` function,
which will determine the value of `diameter`,
and pass it to a `plot(diameter)` function that will take care of the plotting logic.

The biggest issue I see is with the layout:

1. Imports
2. Argument parser
3. Constants
4. Some functions
5. Argument handling
6. Another function
7. The main plotting logic

I suggest to reorganize like this:

1. Imports
2. Constants
3. Helper functions
4. `def plot()`: The main plotting logic
5. `def main():`

   1. Argument parser
   2. Argument handling
6. `if __name__ == '__main__':` guard that simply calls `main()`

After this change, I think it will look a lot better and clearer.